# Which programming language it is?

Tags: programming-languages

I found this script on tenable "getting hired" website...
[image: Found on tenable.com]

Just for curiosity, do you know what language it is?

Comment: looks like javascript and node.js

Comment: Looks like node - so JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `node.js` a server side javascript framework.

More details: Reference to this [here](http://nodejs.org/api/index.html). It is used to build sever side logic to implement parallel services with other server. Its speciality is high throughput for complex logics.

Answer (score 1):

That would be [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) a server-side library written in `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

It is on node.js
As in the Code it Returns a new HTTPS web server object. The options is similar to tls.createServer(). The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to the 'request' event.

Here are the Example Code of the Above Code to get Some Brief Idea About it:

```
// curl -k https://localhost:8000/
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```